# Is there a publication on the speed of sound assuming heat conduction is taken into account?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, resource-recommendations

Is there a publication (possibly a very old one, as the topic is no longer of interest) in which the frequency dependence of the speed of sound is derived assuming heat conduction rather than purely adiabatic conditions? The difference to the adiabatic process lies particularly on the right-hand side of the heat equation. Setting this value to zero gives you the known adiabatic value.

I just had to delete my original question where I asked about a possible error in my own calculation because some people complained that my question was off-topic.

The dependency should be like this:

[image]

I derived some relations which allowed me to calculate this dependency (see red curve), but by including heat conduction the formula for $c(\omega)$ was quite nasty at the end. Therefore, I would like to compare my own result with some published results.

Comment: Can you make the axis labels bigger in the image? If that's a 10 pt font, probably a 16 or 18 should do it.

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mechanical Radiation* by Robert Lindsay discusses the effects of heat flow on sound waves in Section 9.12.  The discussion is primarily couched in terms of attenuation, but as a side result of this discussion he derives the phase velocity of sounds waves in Eq. (20) of that section.

A digital version of the book is available on a one-hour loan [via the Internet Archive.](https://archive.org/details/mechanicalradiat0000lind/page/266/mode/2up) (Or at least it is for me, sitting here in the US;  it's possible that availability differs in other countries.)

Comment: I realize this was the book the OP said they didn't have access to in the now-deleted earlier question;  but on the off-chance that they hadn't found the Internet Archive link, I figured I'd include it.

Comment: only limited preview. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @MichaelW:  At least in the US, you can sign up for an account on the Internet Archive website;  this then allows you to "borrow" the book for one hour, which gives you full access.  Just in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: I ordered it to borrow from my university library.